# How to convert numpy array into LongTensor type Variable in PyTorch?

Tags: python, casting, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to convert numpy `array` into PyTorch `LongTensor` type `Variable` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import torch as th

y = np.array([1., 1., 1.1478225, 1.1478225, 0.8521775, 0.8521775, 0.4434675])
yth = Variable(th.from_numpy(y)).type(torch.LongTensor)
```

However the result I am getting is a rounded off version:

```
tensor([ 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0])
```

How can I keep the precision of numpy `array` while getting `LongTensor` variable?

Expected result should be:

```
tensor([1., 1., 1.1478225, 1.1478225, 0.8521775, 0.8521775, 0.4434675])
```

Answer (score 1):

`LongTensor` represents tensors with values of type `long` / `int64` (c.f. [table in doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html)). Your `float` values are thus converted (i.e. rounded) to integers.

To keep float values, use `FloatTensor` (`float32`) or `DoubleTensor` (`float64`) instead.